# Как достать картинку из ресурса тега <img>?

Tags: java, html, веб-программирование, android-studio

Использую android studio. Нужно скачать картинку и закинуть ее в imageView.
html код страницы программа узнать может, т.е. html страницы имеется. Выделяю подстроку с адресом ресурса картинки,находящейся в теге  атрибут src, который ссылается на пустой html с одной этой картинкой(и соответственно тем же самым адресом). Знаю как загрузить картинку, только в случае если ресурс указывает на саму картинку(метод BitmapFactory(). Есть ли метод делающий то же самое с такой html странице, или можно достать картинку другим способом из этой страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем известная [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Картинки грузятся асинхронно, вам не нужно городить тучу кода с `HttpURLConnection` да еще и в таком сяком плохом `AsyncTask`.

```
String src = img.attr("src"); //Jsoup ?
Picasso.with(this).load(src).into(imageView);
```

Не забудьте прописать разрешение на Интернет в `AndroidManifest`

```
<manifest ... >
....
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
....
<application ... >
```